# Browser tabs turn black

Tags: windows-10, firefox, nvidia-graphics-card

Around since the release of [Firefox 54](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/54.0/releasenotes/) many, many times all tabs have turned to black. Nothing outside of the Firefox UI can be seen and and restarting browser has been necessary. The change is instant and is related to crashing Nvidia driver (I've recently performed a fresh installation).
The color isn't necessarily black, I've seen at least grey, blue and purple in addition.

[image: screenshot]

*the parts in blue are edited*

This issue has been reported on Firefox's bugtracker: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1163440

Comment: I don't know why I can't embed images.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Is the website a valid one? Can you open it another browser? Did you try to reinstall Firefox? Do you have any network issue?

Comment: @Biswa: Yes, yes. This applied to all open tabs, closer to 50 in total. I haven't yet reinstalled, I'd like to find out what may cause this first.

Comment: I have now restored the original image (only Windows taskbar is cropped out) to avoid confusion, please change the embedded image to this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8CMa.png

Comment: Are you running the 32 or 64 bit version of Firefox? Have you tried disabling all extensions? Have you tried a new profile? Is the problem repeatable?

Comment: @DavidPostill: 64-bit. No and no, not yet. I don't know how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I would also recommend testing all the above things DavidPostill mentioned. If you still have no luck, then still include those details in your question so we know what you've ruled out. Also, do you have 'use hardware acceleration' turned on? That could cause random graphical glitches on some machines.

Comment: @BoffinbraiN: Hardware acceleration is on. I now know what causes the issue, see my answer.